# Showing Object Information Depending On a Variable

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a Blackjack game, and I have a function that prints a card in ASCII form.

```
public static void PrintCard()
    {

        Console.SetCursorPosition(x + 0, 0);
        Console.Write(" _____ ");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x + 0, 1);
        Console.Write("|");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x + 1, 1);
        Console.Write(Ten.CardChar);
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x + 6, 1);
        Console.Write("|");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x + 0, 2);
        Console.Write("|");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x + 6, 2);
        Console.Write("|");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x + 0, 3);
        Console.Write("|");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x + 6, 3);
        Console.Write("|");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x + 0, 4);
        Console.Write("|");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x + 6, 4);
        Console.Write("|");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x + 0, 5);
        Console.Write("|");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x + 6, 5);
        Console.Write("|");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x + 0, 6);
        Console.Write("|____");
        if(NameOfCard == "Ten")
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(x + 4, 6);
            Console.Write(Ten.CardChar);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(x + 5, 6);
            Console.Write(Ace.CardChar);
        }

        Console.SetCursorPosition(x + 6, 6);
        Console.Write("|");
```

Since there are different cards, how would I be able to choose which CardChar is shown, depending on a string variable? These are the Card Objects details, the first one is CardName, second is CardValue and third is CardChar.

```
static Card Ace =   new Card("Ace",   0,  "A");
    static Card Two =   new Card("Two",   2,  "2");
    static Card Three = new Card("Three", 3,  "3");
    static Card Four =  new Card("Four",  4,  "4");
    static Card Five =  new Card("Five",  5,  "5");
    static Card Six =   new Card("Six",   6,  "6");
    static Card Seven = new Card("Seven", 7,  "7");
    static Card Eight = new Card("Eight", 8,  "8");
    static Card Nine =  new Card("Nine",  9,  "9");
    static Card Ten =   new Card("Ten",   10, "10");
    static Card Jack =  new Card("Jack",  10, "J");
    static Card Queen = new Card("Queen", 10, "Q");
    static Card King =  new Card("King",  10, "K");
```

Where it says Ten.CardChar, how would I be able to make it work with a string, such as NameOfCard.CardChar? where Ten is stored within NameOfCard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I get your question right but you've asked how you can choose card depending on string? This can be easily done using `Dictionary<>` class :

```
Dictionary<string, Card> _cards = new Dictionary<string, Card>();
//_cards.Add("ace", Ace);
//or
_cards.Add("ace", new Card("Ace",   0,  "A"));
```

Combining this into your code :

```
// instead of :
//if(NameOfCard == "Ten")
//{
//    Console.SetCursorPosition(x + 4, 6);
//    Console.Write(Ten.CardChar);
//}
//else
//{
//    Console.SetCursorPosition(x + 5, 6);
//    Console.Write(Ace.CardChar);
//}

// do this :
if(_cards.ContainsKey(NameOfCard))
{
     Console.SetCursorPosition(x + 4, 6);
     Console.Write(_cards[NameOfCard].CardChar);
}
else
{
    Console.SetCursorPosition(x + 5, 6);
    Console.Write(Ace.CardChar);
}
```

Comment: I want to choose which information is displayed using a string, for example its Ten.CardChar, which is an existing object, but if I do it NameOfCard.CardChar, it doesn't work, even though "Ten" is stored within it. Does that work with your method?

Comment: No because C# is compiled language not interpreted. That's why I recommended using `Dictionary<>` because it acts almost the same as you wanted to.